# How to rename wire mean in PDF file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Personally, I have the following string "E2017010000000601". This character E is for control, after comes the year, then the month and in the last positions comes a user code with a maximum of 7 positions. I would like to know how can I in Python remove those 0 from the middle of the string that are unnecessary.

For example, in the string "E2018090001002202", I do not need these 3 zeros between 9 and 1.
Already in the string "E2017010000000601", I do not need those 7 zeros between 1 and 6 ..
I have over 1000 files with this type of string, and renaming it one by one is tricky. I know that in Python I can rename this huge amount of files, but I did some code and I'm not able to mount the way I explained ... Any help?

Answer (score 1):

This is basic string slicing as long as you are sure the structure is identical for each string.

You can use something like:

```
original_string = "E2017010000000601"
cut_string = str(int(original_string[7:]))
```

This should work because first you remove the first 7 values, the control char, year and month.

Then you turn to integer which removes all the zeroes at the front, then back to string.

Comment: Obrigado todas as respostas ... as principais regras de vocês funcionam perfeitamente...Só preciso agora fazer um loop percorrendo para ele remover os zeros necessariamente antes do 2...Somente estes zeros antes do 2.. Podem me ajudar nessa string "E2018090002006401" ? Estou organizando isso nesse código por enquanto: `import os

for name in os.listdir('./pdf'):
    string_1 = str(name[:7])
    string_2 = str(name[7:])`

Answer (score 0):

Basically the same answer as Alexis, but since I can't comment yet, in a separate answer: since you want to keep the "EYYYYMM" part of the string, the code would be:

```
>>>original_string = 'E2017010000000601'
>>>cut_string= original_string[:7] + str(int(original_string[7:]))

>>>cut_string
'E201701601'
```

A quick explanation: we know what the first seven characters of the string will be, and we want to keep those in the string. Then we add the rest of the string, turned into an integer and back into a string, so that all unnecessary zeroes in front are removed.

Comment: Obrigado todas as respostas ... as principais regras de vocês funcionam perfeitamente...Só preciso agora fazer um loop percorrendo para ele remover os zeros necessariamente antes do 2...Somente estes zeros antes do 2.. Podem me ajudar nessa string "E2018090002006401" ? Estou organizando isso nesse código por enquanto: `import os

for name in os.listdir('./pdf'):
    string_1 = str(name[:7])
    string_2 = str(name[7:])`

Comment: Here, you would then do, in the for loop:

`new_name = string_1+str(int(string_2))` and then, finish with `os.rename(name, new_name)`